# Ontologies : infered classes matching multiple times

Tags: ontology, protege

I'm almost a newbie in ontologies, I use protégé (5.6), robot (https://github.com/ontodev/robot/) and ttl/owl.

My goal is to work with ontologies, ttl and the command line to process and reasonning.

I'm having trouble writing infered classes (not sparql currently) :

```
:Animal rdf:type owl:Class .


:Aligator_Arnaud rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                          :Animal ;
                 :hasName "Arnaud" .


:Alligator_Arthur rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                           :Animal ;
                  :hasName "Arthur" .


:Cat_Charlie rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                      :Animal ;
             :hasName "Charlie" .


:Dog_Alice rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                    :Animal ;
           :hasName "Alice" .
```

I wanted a class matching animals named "Alice"

```
:Animal_named_Alice rdf:type owl:Class ;
                    owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                          owl:onProperty :hasName ;
                                          owl:hasValue "Alice"
                                        ] .
```

Then I wanted a class to match animals begining by A

```
:Animal_regex_A rdf:type owl:Class ;
                owl:equivalentClass [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                      owl:onProperty :hasName ;
                                      owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                                                           owl:onDatatype xsd:string ;
                                                           owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:pattern "A.*"
                                                                                  ]
                                                                                )
                                                         ]
                                    ] .
```

But the Dog "Alice" doesn't show up in "Animal_regex_A" as it is already in "Animal_named_Alice"

I do not understand why, If you could help , I'll be pleased

Thx in advance to the community